# How to detect if user email is hotmail and live using RegEx

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to detect if the user's email is a hotmail or live address, and then echo an error if it is.

Here is what I have tried:

```
if ((preg_match('[a-zA-Z0-9_\.+]+@(live|hotmail)(\.[a-z]{2,3}){1,2}'))){
    echo "We do not accept hotmail and live";
}
```

It does not work. What have I done wrong ?

Comment: If you know that the string is an email address, why not use `strpos`?

Comment: You could simplify by using strstr with '@live' or '@hotmail'.

Comment: I don´t know how. Could you give me an example ?

Comment: considering how many free email hosts there are blocking 2 seems a little pointless

Comment: ehm.. you forgot the second param from preg_match..

Comment: yeah I have forgotten something like this:

if ((preg_match('[a-zA-Z0-9_\.+]+@(live|hotmail)(\.[a-z]{2,3}){1,2}", $_POST['user_email']'))){
        echo"We do not accept hotmail and live";
}

But it does not work !! :S

Comment: Where's your anchors `^` and `$` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seeing as your only purpose is to check if the email is for **live** or **hotmail**, it's not worth over complicating the regular expression, just do something like the following:

**-- UPDATE --**

As pointed out in a comment above, you've missed the second parameter for `preg_match()`

```
if (preg_match('/(.*)@(live|hotmail)\.(.*)/', $emailVariable) != false) {
    echo "Get a real email provider";
}
```

Since you only want to check for `@live` or `@hotmail`, it's safe to ignore the tld and the first part of the email. Demo: http://rubular.com/r/TUlTUxmcQB

***Note**: I'm using `!=` because preg_match() can return `0`, and in this case, 0 matches, and false would equate to the same result.*

Comment: This one picks up `.ca` Hotmail and Live emails, very good :)

Comment: It works now:

if ((preg_match("/^(.*)\@(live|hotmail)\.(.*)$/", $_POST['user_email']))){
    echo"we do not accept hotmail and live";
  
 }

Comment: Use the code I added, but obviously replace $emailVariable with the variable containing the email you wish to valdiate.

Comment: I edited your post to tidy it up and removed the \ from \@. You don't have to escape it.

Comment: Cheers, I need to remember to tidy up after an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex instead...

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_\.+]+@(live|hotmail)(\.com)
```

And here's a demo:   **[DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/SsTFm2KRyW)**

Comment: As hotmail can be like .com.br I prefer to use `[a-zA-Z0-9_\.+]+@(live|hotmail)(\.[a-z]{2,3}){1,2}`

Comment: @LucianoNascimento it's not really necessary.   Since testing up to .com will be sufficient, any extension you add to the end (like .br) is arbitrary.   You can try yourself in the demo I've linked.. .com.br emails are still picked up.

Comment: Nice demo site, although there's no need to check the first part or the extension.

Comment: @ollieread that's a good point...  I was actually working on editing my answer, but stopped to reply to another comment haha.

Comment: There is one factor though. Both Hotmail and Live have `.ca` email addresses available. @Charlie74 which isn't being picked up in your demo.

Comment: They unfortunately don't do .bj or .co.ck which is a shame, as I'd totally make an account if they did.

Answer (score 1):

I used another approach, trying to detect the MXes of the target domain, as hosted exchange will cause similiar problems like hotmail (e.g. silently dropping mails that already had been accepted with "250 ok" by hotmail's servers):

```
function isHotmailAddress($email) {
    $domain = substr(strrchr($email, '@'), 1);

    $mxs = array();
    getmxrr($domain, $mxs);

    $hotmailMxs = preg_grep('/(hotmail|outlook)\.com$/', $mxs);
    return (count($hotmailMxs) > 0);
}
```

Comment: This works great. Thanks. I'm amazed that I am the first up vote. This is much better for preventing users from signing up with hotmail.